# Umgang mit spekulativen Antworten

Tags: discussion

Mitunter kommt es vor, dass in Antworten *spekuliert* wird. Da die Antwortenden kompetente Sprecher*innen des deutschen sind, haben solche Antworten durchaus eine Berechtigung, weil sich in der Gesamtschau etwa dialektale Varianzen zeigen. Mitunter ist auch nach intensiver Recherche nur Spekulation möglich. Auch dann ist es sinnvoll, die Recherche darzustellen, auch wenn sich daraus keine eindeutige Antwort ergibt.
Mitunter - insbesondere bei Fragen die Etymologie betreffend - wird aber auch mehr oder weniger wild spekuliert, und Recherche zeigt, dass die Spekulation haltlos ist und die Antwort daher eher irreführend.

Daher meine beiden (eng verwandten) Fragen:

1. Wie sollen Antwortende mit ihren spekulativen Ansätzen zu einer Antwort umgehen?
2. Wie soll Spekulation bewertet werden?

Comment: Ich denke, dass man das nur auf Basis einer Einzelfallentscheidung machen kann, eben weil, wie Du selbst in der Frage und tofro in seiner Antwort darauf hinweist, dass es sowohl sinvolle als auch sinnlose Fälle von spekulativen Antworten gibt.

Answer (score 5):

Ich glaube nicht, dass es sinnvoll ist, hier Regeln anzugeben, wie Fragen und Antworten zu bewerten sind. Es hält sich i.A. sowieso keiner dran. Bewertung nach eigenem Gutdünken ist einer der Grundsätze von SE (immerhin muß man keine Begründung für eine Bewertung angeben), und die positive Annahme, dass das Gutdünken in der Masse schon richtig sein wird, scheint sich ja zu bestätigen. Ich denke auch, dass jeder, der sich einigermaßen vernünftig mit GSE auseinandersetzt, sich über die Zeit hinweg sein eigenes System an Kriterien setzt, wie er bewertet - Und natürlich den Mindestanspruch an Freundlichkeit erfüllt, indem er kommentiert, warum er downvotet, wenn er's denn tut.

Ich glaube nicht, dass Sprache ohne spekulative Antworten auskommen kann. Ethymologie z.B. ist m.A. nach im Vergleich hochspekulativ.

Andere Teile der Sprache sind sehr konkret - Eine spekulierende Antwort darauf, welchen Fall "wegen" fordert, ist sicher wesentlich schlechter als eine solche, die die Frage nach der Herkunft eines bestimmten Wortes zu beantworten versucht. Von daher ergibt sich eine Einordnung normalerweise automatisch aus dem Bewertungssystem.

Antworten im Sinne von "Ich glaube, das ist ... Das könnte man sicher nachschlagen, aber ich hab' grade keine Lust/Zeit" sind oft sinnlos - Warum antwortet jemand dann überhaupt? Solche Fragen sollten aber auch durch das Bewertungssystem automatisch nach unten rutschen.

Dasselbe gilt für Antworten, die Behauptungen aufstellen, die nicht hinreichend untermauert sind. ("I'm a German native speaker" ist keine hinreichende Untermauerung, wird aber immer wieder gerne genommen...)

Comment: Erschwerend kommt hinzu, dass Fragen zu hinreichend gut untermauerbaren Antworten nicht selten als *general reference* geschlossen werden.

Answer (score -1):

Ich denke, hier sollten Grundsätze gelten, die wissenschaftlichen Prinzipien angelehnt sind und dazu führen, dass in mit den Antworten der Grad der Verlässlichkeit des präsentierten Wissens steigt. Das resultiert in meinen Augen in folgenden Prinzipien:

### @ 1.

#### A)

Spekulationen sollten nicht grundsätzlich verboten sein. Denn es gibt mitunter keine definitiven Antworten und es ist auch schon hilfreich, wenn wir unsere Erfahrungen als Sprecher*innen hier teilen.

#### B)

Antwortende sollten immer **explizit** klar machen, bei welchen Teilen der Antwort sie aufgrund ihrer eigenen Erfahrung als Sprecher*innen des Deutschen spekulieren, und bei welchen Teilen sie sich auf wissenschaftlich gesichertes Wissen berufen. Dabei sollten sie den Grad ihrer Sicherheit quantifizieren. (etwa: "In meinem Dialekt ist X üblich, es kann aber sein, dass in anderen Dialekten Y üblich ist.", etc.)

#### C)

Antwortende sollen darstellen, welche Recherche sie betrieben haben, welche weiteren Schritte sinnvoll wären, um die Lage zu klären, und warum sie eine spekulative Antwort geben (etwa: "Es wäre hilfreich, noch in folgendem Wörterbuch nachzuschlagen, aber ich habe leider keinen Zugang zu diesem Wörterbuch", etc.)

### @ 2.

#### A)

Wenn Antwortende spekulieren, ohne dies explizit kenntlich zu machen, sollte die Antwort -1 erhalten.

#### B)

Wenn Recherche ergibt, dass die Spekulation nicht haltbar ist, sollte dies in einem Kommentar vermerkt werden. Wenn die Dauer der Recherche auch dem Antwortenden hätte zugemutet werden können, sollte die Antwort -1 erhalten.